# What's the benefit of Spring *Aware interfaces vs. injecting required objects?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

Spring has various `*Aware`-interfaces, eg. `ApplicationContextAware` which add a setter to the implementer. Does using these interfaces have any benefits over simply requesting the dependency via regular DI means (eg. constructor injection).

In other words, when should I prefer

```
@Service
class MyService implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

over

```
@Service
class MyService implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public MyService(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

or

```
@Service
class MyService implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
}
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All 3 examples have the same effect.
There are just some nuances, and in the end it's a matter of style.

In the **first example** - Spring scans for components implementing certain marker interfaces, `ApplicationContextAware` is one of them, and executes method of the interface with actual applicationContext instance provided in the parameter by the DI runtime.

**Second example** works only in Spring 4.3 and higher.
When your bean has single constructor that specifies its dependencies, then dependency injection by constructor is assumed even without annotations.

**Third one** is just plain injection by `@Autowired` annotation.

There is no simple answer to which way is better.
Documentation for `ApplicationContextAware` interface even suggests that you might be better with other ways if you need applicationContext just for bean lookup (e.g. when you have to use method injection technique).

To sum it up:
the choice between 1st, 2nd and 3rd is just a choice between different IoC/DI flavour and also if to skip an optional `@Autowired` annotation or not.

*P.S.*
your 2nd and 3rd examples do not have to implement `ApplicationContextAware` interface at all. In fact the compiler will complain that you are not providing the setter for `ApplicationContect` object.

Answer (score 0):

in your code snippets

1. in first approach is completely fine and that's they standard way to get that
   object.
2. in second approach i am not sure but probably you will get error bcoz you are not
   overriding `setApplicationContext()` method.
3. last  but not least in third approach you will get error  bcoz you are not
   overriding `setApplicationContext()` method.

   if we override `setApplicationContext()` in third snippet then IOC Container first
   inject null bcoz `@Autowired` cannot inject `ApplicationContext` object

   **[Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
   "`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.getBean(String, java.lang.Class)`"
   because "this.ctx" is null]**

   then overriden setApplicationContext() executes and it will inject `ApplicationContext` object in the say way as approach 1. so 1 and 3 are same

**CONCLUSION ::** to inject spring supplied special propeties/object like `ApplicationContext` object we must implement `ApplicationContextAware` interfact (`XxxAware` interface for respective properties/object)